# VBA wont click gif nested in a tag

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into an issue with my macro that works on Excel 2013 but will not work on Excel 2010. I am trying to click a gif that is on the webpage but for some reason it does not "see" it.

The HTML I am using is as follows:

```
<a href="#" style="color:#009900;">
<img src='images/CheckMarkGreen.gif' border=0 alt='Select This Item'>
</a>
```

And the VBA I am using is:

```
Dim imgElm

For Each imgElm In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    If imgElm.innertext = "images/CheckMarkGreen.gif" Then
    imgElm.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image elements don't have an innerText (maybe you mean innerHTML?)

Easier maybe to check the `alt` attribute:

```
If imgElm.getAttribute("alt") = "Select This Item" Then
    imgElm.Click
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: I tried using the alt attribute instead but that still did not allow it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim imgElm as IHTMLElement

For Each imgElm In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    If imgElm.getAttribute("src") = "images/CheckMarkGreen.gif" Then
        imgElm.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

OR

```
Dim imgElm as HTMLImg

For Each imgElm In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    If imgElm.src = "images/CheckMarkGreen.gif" Then
        imgElm.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried using both option you provided however I get a Compile Error User-defined type not defined.

Comment: Yeh you have to set the References to the HTML Object Library under Tools-->References in the VBE

Comment: How do you know that the image is clicked? I don't see the rest of your code, or any event that would trigger when it's clicked. What is the error or failure result?

Comment: Updated the references however it still does not click the GIF. I would know that the img is clicked because it should load a new page. It does not load the new page and I get an error because the next piece of code that clicks another button is unable to be found due to the page not loading. Sorry for the long explanation but it felt like it was the only way to get it out. haha